# Jenkins Pipeline Sourcecode Missing

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Created Jenkins pipeline using pipeline script.
After first  run when i click on configure and see the  pipeline code it shows empty.I have  try to execute the pipeline it run but the code is empty. 
I am unable to update my pipeline or my code as it is empty.
Jenkins Version i use  2.204.2. 
I have tried copying pipeline multiple time but it gets blank after i run the job.

Sample pipeline code which i tried executing:

[image: Sample pipeline code which i tried executing]

Comment: Have you clicked Save or Apply on the configuration page?

Comment: Yes I have did that configuration is saved so only when i execute second time it Run .

Comment: I have tried taking checkout of Jenkins file from git repository.Still it has same problem the settings get clears and it shows empty when i open it for the next time. Did Any one face this kind of issue .

Comment: Check Jenkins logs for any error. Maybe the installation folder is damaged or there are not enough permissions for saving settings to file.

Comment: If issue with saving  or permission  Jenkins shouldn't save the free style project also i dont have issue with the free style project

Comment: @MukeshV were you able to resolve this? I too am facing similar issue where if I replay a job, the pipeline is there, but if I open Project Configuration, it is missing and shows blank. If I do any change inside the Project Configuration (apart from Pipeline) and save, it gets saved with empty pipeline. I have recently upgraded Jenkins from v2.164.2 to v2.222.4

Answer (score 0):

Create declarative pipeline and use Jenkins pipeline V2. Create a Jenkinsfile in your repository. Create a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins. Add SCM and choose the branch(es) to build. Click on build now at the left-hand side. After it builds, you should be able to hit replay and change your pipeline.

Comment: Hi RamKamath, I can keep the  pipeline script Jenkins file , but the issue is not that i have to find out why the jenkins script is not saving while i create pipeline job.